# jquery select tag not being brought to front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following function, which brings a given element to the front, and changes a couple of properties. The element in question is a select box.

```
function expandTags(event){
  var pos = $(this).position();
  $(this).css("position", "absolute");
  $(this).css("left", pos.left + "px");
  $(this).css("top", pos.top + "px");
  $(this).css("height", $(this)[0].scrollHeight + 20 + "px");
  $(this).attr("size", $(this).data("list_item").data("tags").names.length);
  $(this).css("zIndex", 9999);
}
```

The code works, all except for the zIndex - while the element does get updated to have this value, it seems to have no affect. When the select box's height is expanded, it overlaps another select box (essentially identical) in a row below it. Which is in front of this select box. Regardless of what I set that boxes zIndex to, it always remains on top.

The HTML of the boxes after the action is as follows: the one that should be on top.

```
<select style="width: 100px; height: 173px; position: absolute; z-index: 9999; left: 252px; top: 0px;" size="11" class="tags" name="StaggeredMessage[0][message][tags]" id="StaggeredMessage_0_message_tags" >
    <option></option>
    ....
</select>
```

The one that should be below (but is on top):

```
<select style="width: 100px; height: 80px; position: relative; z-index: 100;" size="4" id="StaggeredMessage_1_message_tags" name="StaggeredMessage[1][message][tags]" class="tags" title="Default for Carrier Id: ">
    <option></option>
    ....
</select>
```

They are in different relatively positioned

and  tags.

I can't see what the cause of this could be, any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: on a different but related matter, for better performance, try  not to abuse the use of $(this), you may place it in a variable like: var $this = $(this). In addition, you may write the css properties and values as an object, then pass it to the $this.css(). That way you will call the function once and your code will look cleaner as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly proficient in JS, but just begining with jQuery really, good things to remember!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue can be resolved by also setting the z-index of the parent elements (not the direct parent, but the highest parent on the same level as the for me this was a

tag about 4 nodes up the chain. Its interesting that the only elements affected by this were select boxes, as the textareas and labels I had were unaffected. Indeed the

element that required the z-index set was also appearing under the item.

Very strange, but solved now. And a good one to remember.

Answer (score 1):

`zIndex` is used when you are setting it using the `style` property. for example: `element.style.zIndex = 9;` - when doing it using the with `.css()` or when addressing the style property name using a string, you need to use `z-index`.

Change

```
$(this).css("zIndex", 9999);
```

to

```
$(this).css("z-index", 9999);
```

and it should work.

Note: You can also do it as `$(this).css({zIndex: 9999});` - Where the style property name is not in quotes.

Comment: I tried this initially, but no such luck, as I said in the question, the z-index is being updated correctly, but the select box is not coming to the front.